# Discount Based on Qty in Stock

Tags: php, magento, catalog

I need to give discount based on qty in stock, below are my conditions

Suppose I have 50 qty in Stock
1. When user buys between 1 to 10 he will 5% discount.
2. When user buys between 11 to 25 he will 3% discount.
3. When user buys between 26 to 50 he will 2% discount.

I have tried using catalog rule and shopping rule but nothing workout.

Please suggest how I can achieve above goal.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tier-group-price-percentages.html or try to search 'tier price percentage' on connect

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 rules in Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules

Rule #1
[image: Rule #1]

Rule #2
[image: Rule #2]

Rule #3
[image: Rule #3]

Comment: Hello ToxasBes,I have to give discount based on qty instock not in cart

Comment: Hi Suraj Nirmal, I'm afraid what Magento don't have such ability by default. You need to write own extension whih implement it or search for existing 3rd-party extensions which can manage discounts based on product stock quantity, for example: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/discount-conditions-extension-collection-edition.html